# Best practices for installing VSCODE in an classroom with bad internet connection

Tags: windows, macos, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, installation

We have a coding class running in a region with low bandwidth. We'd like the students to have VS Code and Google Chrome. There's a NAS device in the classroom that I'd like to load instances of VSCode and chrome onto, but I'm unsure specifically what I should load onto it.

Should I make copies of the applications themselves and store that onto the NAS? Or should I download all of the installers for Mac/Windows and store *those* instead? Will running those installation scripts eat up more bandwidth downloading content, or are they self contained?

Appreciate any insight you might have.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the installer can take a very long time even on good bandwidth to install or update VS2019/VSCode and seem to be not self-contained (you can download pretty much any extras/features because they all come from the internet). If you don't mind not updating constantly then I would say just do your first choice and install the whole application once and then make copies of it to move it onto your device/s to just do one installation instead of multiple.

Additionally make sure you get all the distributables/extras you will need for whatever coding language you will be teaching (e.g. C++ redistributable for coding C++ or C based languages)